# TAC (Talend Administration center) synchronisation problem with the job server ( job still showing "running" in tac though the job finished)

Tags: talend, tac

I have an issue that occurs in DI 6.2 with a job that stucks with the status "running" on TAC but when i verify directly in the job server i find that job finished executing,

I can't find the root cause for this issue, the logs on the server doesn't contain errors,

I think the communication between the TAC and the job server is broken!

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a defect.  Of course a reboot will solve the problem, but it requires a reboot whenever the problem reappears.

There is a patch available for TAC that should solve the problem.  Please raise a Talend support ticket.

Answer (score 0):

this could be caused by a restart of your TAC, which messed up job statuses. 
You can check job status in EXECUTIONTASK table of your installation DB (if you don't know which DB it is, check Configuration>Database tab with an admin user in TAC). There you can update 'STATUS' field in this table for this job.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but how can we prevent this problem from happening?

Comment: Don't know exactly. But be sure that all your jobs are stopped before stopping TAC for example.